# Telegram. Телеграмовский сервер получает ответ 404

Tags: yii2, apache, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста я использую веб хуки для бота. При каждом обновлений веб хуков сервер Телеграма делает POST запрос на мой сервер (указанный адрес в веб хуках), и видит 404. Хотя по факту данный ресурс существует. В чем может быть проблема? при чем он временами видит этот ресурс а временами отдает 404. Есть у кого нибудь догадки на этот счет?

Comment: Не знаю. Надо колеса попинать, фары протереть, всеми дверьми хлопнуть. А еще, посмотреть access.log и error.log, там все написано.

Comment: Что за хостинг (платный/бесплатный)? Если бесплатный, то часто встречаются те, которые приостанавливают машину при простое более N минут/часов и возобновляют доступ при обращении. Какой используется сертификат: самоподписанный или нет? Как сказал @gbg, сперва нужно в логи глянуть. И инфы по больше, а то по данному описанию проблемы, мало что можно сказать.